# How to convert 2nd order 2d equation to to first order

Tags: numerical-methods

There is the equation for the gravity orbit:

```
 r' = v
 v' = -r/|r|^3
```

To solve it i need to convert to first order. It is clear that right side is the gradient:

```
grad(1/r) = -r/|r|^3
```

But for the cartesian it looks strange because of *|r|* and i am getting like:

```
rx' = vx
ry' = vy
vx' = -rx/|r|^3
vy' = -ry/|r|^3
```

Comment: The equations you wrote are already of the first order (there is no double derivative)

Comment: Note that $|r|$ is now the Euclidean norm of the vector $(r_x,r_y)$.